# Ошибка Allowed memory size в PHP

Tags: php

Поставил я в memory_limit 1024M, возникает ошибка: **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes)**
Я побывал и больше ставить, всёравно ошибка. А ошибка в результате такого кода:
PHP:

1. $s = file('std.txt');

Файл весит 50мб, 3.5 млн строк в нём. Можете сказать почему? Да, и я проверял, на другом серваке работает, там memoty_limit 1024M. В чём проблема не пойму

Comment: Скорее всего - ставили недостаточно больше :)
Либо проблема не в этой строчке

Comment: Ну а почему же на другом сервер работает? там такой же memory_limit. Я к тому, что может кроме memory_limit ещё что-то влияет на это?

Comment: На ошибку ** Allowed memory size....** ничего кроме лимит не влияет и влиять не может по определению, смею предположить что у вас проблема не в этой строчке

Comment: Да, возможно, а если после неё идёт fopen?

Comment: для начала - убедитесь в том что у него устанавливается новый лимит памяти

Comment: Ну это видно, т.к. of 1073741824, т.е. 1024мб.

Comment: А на сервере вообще столько памяти есть? + вы уверены, что вам нужно обязательно прочитать сразу весь файл?

Comment: нет, а как можно не сразу весь? Мне вообще нужно прочитать от заданной позиции до заданной позиции, т.е., например от 5 по 500 строку

Comment: > На ошибку Allowed memory size.... ничего кроме лимит не влияет и влиять не может по определению
К чему такая категоричность? На расход памяти в PHP может влять уйма факторов: начиная от разрядности операционной системы и заканчивая подключенными расширениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне вообще нужно прочитать от заданной позиции до заданной позиции, т.е., например от 5 по 500 строку

```
$result = array();
$from = 5;
$to = 500;
if ($f = fopen('std.txt', 'rb')) {
  $n = 0;
  while (!feof($f)) {
    $n++;
    $str = fgets($f);
    if ($n < $from) continue;
    if ($n > $to) break;
    $result[] = $str; // если есть возможность, здесь лучше не собирать массив, а обработать строку сразу
    }
  fclose($f);
  } else die('Не получилось открыть файл');
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Не за что)
И прошу прощения, обновил, добавил закрытие файла)

Comment: А я вот ещё спрошу не по теме, у меня запись в файл в цикле идёт, и если её остановить в браузере крестиком, то программа не прекратит работать, и поможет только перезагрузка сервера. Что можно в таком случае сделать, чтобы программа останавливалась? Ну и даже из ряда фантастики возьму: чтобы при остановке выполнялся маленький скрипт, чтобы записать на какой позиции остановилась запись. А то у меня скрипт считывает с одного файла, а в другой записывает переработанную информацию по строке.

Comment: На коленке можно сделать так: добавить в цикл

    if (is_file('close.txt')) { unlink('close.txt'); break; }

и добавьте себе куда-нибудь ссылочку, при клике на которую будет создаваться файл `close.txt`. Типа того:

    if (!empty($_GET['forcestop'])) {
      file_put_contents('close.txt', '1');
      header('location: ?');
      exit;
      }
    echo '<a href="?forcestop=1">Остановить</a>';

Comment: Спасибо, т.е. каждый раз в close.txt записывать текущею позицию? Т.е. каждый, например, i++ записывать этот i в close.txt? А при нажатии на остановить закрывать файлы с которыми работал?

Comment: Не-не, завести какой-то файл вроде "lastpos.txt". Во время остановки цикла вписать в него номер последней строки. Если скрипт не останавливали - под конец запишите в него 0, чтобы в следующий раз скрипт не повторил работу с той строки. А когда запускаете в следующий раз - берите номер строки из этого файла, тогда он просто продолжит работу.

А close.txt - это "файл-флаг", его наличие просто говорит о том, что цикл надо прервать.